# Foreign key con varias columnas en migración Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, activerecord

Así agrego una clave foránea con una migración en Rails:

```
add_foreign_key :teachers, :departamentos, name: "teachers_departamento_id", 
                column: :codigo_departamento, primary_key: :codigo
```

Pero ¿cómo puedo indicar varias columnas en `column` y en `primary_key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograrlo necesitarías utilizar SQL en tu migración, la cual puede variar dependiendo la base de datos que utilices; acá te muestro un ejemplo utilizando *MySQL*:

```
class AddForeignKeyToTeachers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "ALTER TABLE teachers ADD CONSTRAINT teachers_departamentos_fk FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2) REFERENCES departamentos (column1, column2);"
  end

  def down
    execute "ALTER TABLE teachers DROP FOREIGN KEY teachers_departamentos_fk;"
  end
end
```

Notas:

- La migración únicamente genera la llave foránea y asume que las columnas requeridas ya existen en la tabla.
- *ActiveRecord* no sabe como utilizar llaves compuestas, el efecto de esta migración únicamente afecta a nivel base de datos, pero la lógica para su uso en Rails deberás determinarla tu a través del modelo<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Para llaves primarias compuestas puedes utilizar la gema [Composite Primary Keys](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys)</sup>

---

Si no quieres *pelear* con Rails (y la lógica de tu aplicación lo permite) podrías optar por utilizar como llave primaria la columna con valor autonumérico que genera la migración por defecto, y generar un índice compuesto con restricción (i.e. que la combinación de las columnas sea única) para emular el comportamiento de una llave primaria compuesta; esto lo puedes lograr  utilizando `add_index` en tu migración:

```
class AddIndexToTeachers< ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :teachers, [:column1, :column2], unique: true
  end
end
```

Claro que las relaciones las tendrías que hacer siempre a través de la llave primaria (i.e. columna con valor autonumérico).

La solución óptima dependerá de la complejidad de tu aplicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Con tu aclaración ya puedo buscar alternativas para tratar el problema.

Comment: @JohanDonadoB. Excelente! Si consideras que la respuesta resuelve tu duda, no olvides marcarla como aceptada (da clic a la paloma). Suerte!